# Need to compare the values with greater or less than with bean shell processor/JSR processor script

Tags: jmeter

Requirement :-

1. I have a API call in which I am getting a total_count in response header (let say 3500).
2. I want to compare the this count with any specific no either defined as variable (let say ${max_count} = 5000)
3. Now I want to iterate the loop with a condition say :
   if  total_count < ${max_count}, then loop should iterate for max_count
   else :- loop count should iterate for total_count only.

How can I do that with bean shell processor/JSR processor.

Can you please suggest any solution.

PS :- I don't want to use any property function or groovy function here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using any suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) like this:

```
def loops = (vars.get('total_count') as int) < (vars.get('max_count') as int) ? vars.get('max_count') : vars.get('total_count')

vars.put('loops', loops as String)
```

and then use `${loops}` in the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller)

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)